# Does the position of a ship's nacelles affect impulse travel?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, propulsion

How does impulse work on a Federation ship? Are the impulse engines part of the nacelles?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The three questions are related, but for instance the second and third can be answered independently.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can determine, [impulse engines](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Impulse_engine) are third-law compliant rockets. This means that thrust vectoring relative to the starship's center of mass is important. Now, I admit that earlier starships designs are problematic in this area. I had a Physics professor that would joke about how the TOS Enterprise would tumble through space due to its nacelles being placed too high.

[image: TOS Enterprise]

There may be an in-universe counterargument that I'm not aware of, but it would be more efficient to have the impulse engines in the right place regardless.

Newer designs seem to take this into consideration, such as the TNG Enterprise. The impulse engines are the red rectangles pointing behind the ship.

[image: TNG Enterprise]

In this case, the impulse engines are not on the nacelles, but on the saucer and the stardrive sections. Their placement suggests that they would be balanced around the Enterprise's center of mass, which would likely be just above the deflector dish.

Voyager's impulse engines are on the warp nacelles, so their position does change when the nacelles move into "warp mode".

[image: Voyager]

It is a small difference, but one can speculate that the lower position is more efficient for impulse travel because the engines are better aligned with the ship's center of mass. In rocketry, even a small misalignment can be catastrophic.

Unfortunately I can't find any concrete references to this in the show, but this explanation is consistent with the parts of Physics that are the same between the Star Trek universe and our own.

Comment: Your first sentence seems most responsive, so it could use some canonical sources.

Comment: The impulse thrusters are supposed to be located in the back of the saucer on the original Enterprise, see the diagram [here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Constitution_class_model_(original)?file=Constitution-class_USS_Enterprise_NCC-1701_finalized_plan_views_by_Matt_Jefferies.jpg) by Enterprise designer [Matt Jefferies](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Matt_Jefferies), from [p. 178](https://archive.org/details/makingofstartrek00whit/page/n211/mode/2up) of the 1968 book [The Making of Star Trek](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Making_of_Star_Trek).